# What are these nodules underneath the leaves of this bush?

Tags: identification, shrubs

**What are these nodules that are underneath the leaves and on the stems of this bush *everywhere*?**

I'm in Georgia in April 2020.

I don't know what kind of bush it is, but you can see from the inset photo that it grows back within months after being pruned.

I don't recall seeing these dots in years past.

Should I be doing anything about this?

**If these are pests we should get rid of, we'd prefer an organic way, if possible.**

[image: bush]

UPDATE: Another photo
[image: closeup]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like aphids, sucking fluid from the plant. I would use Malathion but I think it is politically incorrect. One alternative is to buy a very large number of lady bugs online.

Comment: Thanks blacksmith37. I added a new photo; these looks like bugs but not exactly like aphids (https://www.google.com/search?q=aphids&source=lnms&tbm=isch) but I guess there are varieties.

Comment: Malathion would still fix them.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: How to Use Household Dish Soap to Control Aphids: https://homeguides.sfgate.com/use-household-dish-soap-control-aphids-40992.html I've had good luck with this on my Carpenter plants (*Silphium perfoliatum*)over the years.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger interesting, thank you!